# What does it mean if I can render to a floating point texture, but I'm told it's not supported?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

When I try to do the following, an alert box says "no".

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
if (!ext) {
     alert("no");   
}
```

OES_texture_float also does not appear in my list of supported extensions.

Based off of [this article](http://codeflow.org/entries/2013/feb/22/how-to-write-portable-webgl/#floating-point-textures), I then tried to determine if I can render to floating point textures.

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0,gl.RGBA, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

var check = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
if(check != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
    alert("yes");
}
else{
    alert("no");
}
```

I get the alert yes. What does it mean that the extension is not supported, but I can apparently still render those textures? What can I do with just the second ability?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check is backward. It should say

```
if (check === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  alert("yes");
```

Also you got an error you'd likely see in the JavaScript console

```
WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: texImage2D: invalid type
```

Comment: Wow, I copied that straight from the tutorial so assumed it was correct. Thank you very much!